# How to create a frame in a Latex document?

Tags: box, frame

I am having a problem with creating a frame that looks like the picture. Somebody could show me how to do it? Thank you guys so much.[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: If you have a local distro, run  `texdoc tcolorbox`.

Comment: I have another question, how can I make the outline border thicker?

Answer (score 1):

Very simple with `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{problem}[1][]{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colback=white,
    colbacktitle=white,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    boxrule=.6pt,
    titlerule=.2pt,
    toptitle=3pt,
    bottomtitle=3pt,
    title=Problem~\thetcbcounter,
    #1}
    
\begin{document}
    Some test before the first problem
    Some test before the first problem
    Some test before the first problem
    \begin{problem}
    Test of the first problem
    Test of the first problem
    Test of the first problem
    Test of the first problem
    \end{problem}
    Some text after the first problem and before the second problem
    Some text after the first problem and before the second problem
    \begin{problem}
    Test of the second problem
    Test of the second problem
    Test of the second problem
    \end{problem}
    Some test after the second problem
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What a great code, thanks CarLaTex so much!

Comment: @ Hưng Trần You have to vote AND accept for this nice work! I voted for!

Comment: @HưngTrần You're welcome! Please look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that.